# Using old vanilla beans

Tags: storage-lifetime, vanilla

I have vanilla beans that have been in my jar of vanilla for about a year. I've now used up that vanilla. Are the beans still good to add to some other vanilla I am making (along with new beans)?

Comment: What will you be making with the beans? You don't make vanilla, you use it.

Comment: What do you mean by "jar of vanilla"? Vanilla sugar? Neutral alcohol with vanilla beans in?

Answer (score 1):

The beans are fine to use for a little extra flavoring. If you're making a Crème Pâtissière, for example, you can add your extra beans in along with seeds and pods from a fresh bean.